# Group based auto increment

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

In my employees table entities are `employee_id, name, type`

there are 3 types of employees. those are : ST, WF, WP

So when a employees info enter into the database table would be like this

```
employee_id  name     type
WP 1          john      WP
WP 2          doe       WP
ST 1          jhonny    ST
WF 1          tuna      WF
ST 2          tian      ST
WP 3          Rian      WP
```

Problem here is How to enter `employee_id` auto increment based on type

there is one solution could be like it will count employee type from table and add `count+1` based on type. but the problem when multiple user enter employees database into table multiple user will get same count and `employee_id` won't be unique.

How do i get optimum solution? Thanks

Comment: Is there any reason why you want them all to start from 1.  What happens if someone leaves - do you want to re-organise the values again? An auto-increment key would be a lot easier.

Comment: 'How to enter employee_id auto increment based on type' - you have to write something yourself MYSQL does not have such built in functionality.

Comment: This is a bad design. Just store an auto-incrementing id for employees, and another column for their type.

Comment: @p.salmon well, MyISAM obviously has this functionality built-in, but I wouldn't advocate its use.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to create unique index on (employee_id, type) and catch exceptions.

**For eloquent:**

```
$employee = new Employee($data);

$saved = false;

while (!$saved) {
    try {
        $count = Employee::where('type', $employee->type)->count();
        $employee->employee_id = $employee->type . ' ' . ($count + 1);
        $employee->save();
        $saved = 1;
    } catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {
    }
}
```

**For non-eloquent:**

```
$type = 'some type';    
$saved = false;

while (!$saved) {
    try {
        $count = DB::table('employees')->where('type', $type)->count();

        DB::table('employees')->insert([
            'employee_id' => $type . ' ' . ($count + 1)
            ...
        ]);

        $saved = 1;
    } catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: The idea of reading all of the records for this type in each loop sounds excessive and would not be very efficient.

Comment: @NigelRen your statement is only half true, depending on the size of the table and the number of concurrent users. In fact, now he is doing the same thing, and with a limited number of users, the difference will not be noticeable. `max()` should work faster, but he has string prefix in ids.

Comment: Isn't that making a lot of assumptions.  You don't know what his code is doing, you don't know how large the table is intended to get or the number of users.  Sometimes the problem is that people write code that works in testing and then when it goes live it grinds to a halt due to poor coding choices.

Comment: @NigelRen This is all controversy. Suggest your option?

Comment: Not sure why you claim it's controversial, but how about a simple alternative - put the count outside the loop.  Then it will only do this once - the loop itself may fail a couple of times (at most) but the time taken will be a lot less (you will need to increment a counter rather than just +1)

Comment: @NigelRen We can't do this. We should increment actual count. Count outside loop is not actual.